# $\log \log (\alpha)$ transcendental??

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, transcendental-numbers

$\log \log (\alpha)$ transcendental?? ($\alpha$ algebraic $\neq 0$ and $1$)

I supposed $\log \log (\alpha)=\beta$ , $\beta$ transcendental. Then $\log(\alpha)=e^{\beta}$ and it is know $e^{\beta}$ is transcendental.

Comment: What do you assume about $\alpha$?

Comment: $\alpha$ is algebraic $\neq 0, 1$

Comment: The number $e$ is not element of any p-adic field (p odd prime) but $e^p\in\mathbb Q_p$ . 
Could this perhaps help?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if we can prove it right now, but it is likely.

An interesting [conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture) by Schanuel states that

> If $x_1,\dotsc,x_n$ are complex numbers linearly independent over $\Bbb{Q}$, then
>   $$
> \text{trdeg}_{\Bbb{Q}}(x_1,\dotsc,x_n,e^{x_1},\dotsc,e^{x_n}) \geq n
> $$

If this conjecture holds then
$$
2 \leq \text{trdeg}_{\Bbb{Q}}(\alpha, \log(\alpha), \log(\alpha), \log\log(\alpha)) = \text{trdeg}_{\Bbb{Q}}(\log(\alpha), \log\log(\alpha)) \leq 2
$$
so $\log(\alpha)$ and $\log\log(\alpha)$ would be algebraically independent for every $\alpha \in \bar{\Bbb{Q}} \setminus \{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NOT. We are sure $\log\alpha$ is trascendental because $\alpha$ is algebraic neither $0$ nor $1$ but the log of a trascendental may be either algebraic or trascendental ($\log e=1$ and $e$ is trascendental)

Comment: In order for this argument to be a proof, rather than just finding a gap in OP's proposed proof, you would need something like $e^e$ is algebraic, to quote your example.

Comment: I did not want to find  any mistake of anyone. Just give an example in which log of a transcendental is algebraic ($\log e^n=n$). Now I see the specific point of log log

Answer (score 0):

lindemann weirstrauss theorem states that $$ e^x$$ is transcendental For x is algebraic $$(x)$$ not equal to 0 1.
If x is transcendental then $$e^x$$ is transcendental or Algebraic. x=e^log_e(x) here x is algebraic so $$log_e(x) $$ is transcendental . Now $$log_e(x)$$=e^ln(ln(x)) here ln(x) is transcendental so ln(ln(x)) is algebraic or transcendental. Read possibly transcendental numbers on wikipeidia.